# Несколько строк в input type=text

Tags: html, css, javascript

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы в `<input type=text>` вмещалось несколько строк? Если да, то каким образом?

Comment: а зачем? Чем вас не устраивает textarea?

Comment: Не семантично. В textarea втыкаются тексты а мне нужно воткнуть заголовок. Это заголовок у меня такой длинный.

Comment: подождите, какой заголовок? И почему его можно засунуть в input, но нельзя в textarea?

Comment: @DreamChild потому что он ерунду придумал какую то для себя)

Comment: @СаматЖанбеков используйте стандартные компоненты, `textarea` отлично отработает, почти так же как и `input`, только он уже будет многострочным. Средствами CSS его можно превратить в копию `input`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea